# Node JS spawn of child_process

Tags: javascript, node.js, spawn, raspberry-pi-zero

I'm spawning a command to play an audio stream with `mpg123`, which works fine. I expose a method to kill the process as well which also works well, but I can't figure out how to get output from the said command.

No events are fired on the child processes `stdout`, going by the docs it should work - what could be the issue here?

One solution I've found is to set `stdio` property of `spawn` to `inherit`, but then `spawn` returns null, which is not ideal as I can't create a handle to kill it later.

I'm running this on a Pi Zero with Node 10.24.

```
export const streamFactory = (cb: (data: string) => void) => {
  try {
    const st = spawn("mpg123", [configManager.getStreamUrl()]);

    st.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
      console.log(data);
      cb(data);
    });

    return {
      close: () => {
        st.kill("SIGINT");
      },
    };
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, `mpg123` outputs its data on `stderr`, not `stdout`. Making the switch works like a charm, go figure.

Comment: This, and another word of warning: if you try to put commands into mpg123 using the spawned process, ```child.stdin.write("q")``` won't work, unless you start mpg123 with the -R remote option.